# Why is a list sort nlogn

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have tried googling this but have been confused. As it is the very start of an online course and we have not been introduced to concepts such as merge sort.

We are given  the pseudo code below and told it has nlogn operations.

```
MaxPairwiseProductBySorting(A[1 . . . n]): 
Sort(A)
return A[n − 1] · A[n]
```

I understand why something like the below could have n^2 operations. But am totally lost at the former of where the nlogn comes from.

```
MaxPairwiseProductNaive(A[1 . . . n]): product ← 0
    fori from1ton:
        forj fromi+1ton: 
            product←max(product,A[i]·A[j])
return product
```

Comment: An optimal sort performs O(n log n) comparisons.

Comment: @PaulHankin an optimal comparison-sort. Counting-sort for example can do with `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to sort lists. Under certain conditions a list can be sorted as quickly as O(n), but generally it will take O(n log n). The exact analysis depends on the specific sort, but the gist is that most of these sorts work like this:

- Break the problem of sorting the list into 2 smaller sorting problems
- Repeat

... with some way of handling very small sorts.

The log(n) comes from repeatedly splitting the problem. The n comes from the fact that we have to sort all of the parts, which will total to n since we haven't gotten rid of anything.

It would help you to read up on a specific sort to understand this better. Mergesort & quicksort are two common sorts, and Wikipedia has good articles on both.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption in this code is that you're dealing with a so called comparison-sort that orders elements of the array by comparing two at a time.

Now for sorting `n` elements that way, we can generate a decision-tree that considers all potential binary decisions until the tree is ordered starting from an arbitrary input-permutation. The minimum achievable height for that decision-tree would then be a lower bound for any comparison-sort algorithm.

E.g. for `n = 3`:

```
                   -------------1:2-----------------
                  <=                               >
          --------2:3-------                ------2:3-----
         <=                >               <=            >
      {1,2,3}         ----1:3----       ---1:3---      {3,2,1}
                     <=         >      <=       >
                    {1,3,2}  {3,1,2}  {2,1,3} {2,3,1}
```

The decision-tree must obviously contain all possible permutations of `n` values as leafs. Otherwise there would exist input-permutations that our algorithm couldn't properly sort. This means the tree must have at least `n!` leafs. So we have

```
n! <= nleafs <= 2^h
```

where `h` is the height of our tree. Taking the logarithm of both sides, we obtain

`n lg n >= lg 1 + lg 2 + ... + lg n = lg n! >= h`

So `h = Omega(n lg n)`. Since `h` is the length of the longest path in the decision-tree, it is also the lower bound on the number of comparisons in the worst case. So any comparison-sort is `Omega(n lg n)`.